# AS400 DB2 Does not support JOIN with = 'xxxxxxxxx'?

Tags: db2, where-clause, inner-join, ibm-midrange

Im trying to do a inner join and add a where clause on it.

The where clause is a number given by API call and retrive the lettres written by a person.

When i add a MATCHING where clause its not working.

here is the sql query :

```
SELECT IDLETTRE, IDPATIENT, NUMINAMI, DATELETTRE, FILEDEST,
PBNAME                                                     
FROM                                                       
MEDLIB.OVLETTRES  INNER JOIN MEDCPOF.SPTML0 ON             
IDPATIENT = SPTML0.DZL6                                    
where NUMINAMI = '16721216370'
```

Give me the error : Selection error involving field *N.

When i add a NON matching where clause it give my and emplty rows reponse as expected...

```
SELECT IDLETTRE, IDPATIENT, NUMINAMI, DATELETTRE, FILEDEST,
PBNAME                                                     
FROM                                                       
MEDLIB.OVLETTRES  INNER JOIN MEDCPOF.SPTML0 ON             
IDPATIENT = SPTML0.DZL6                                    
where NUMINAMI = '123'
```

[image: Empty rows as expected]

I expected the rows with the where condition and not an error..

Comment: I tried with alias etc but not working too.
Its literraly when the where clause find rows....
When i remove the where clause the query is working

Comment: What is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question? Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: Please: Clarify via edits, not comments. Delete & flag obsolete comments. Use standard spelling & punctuation. Indent code reasonably per syntax. Avoid social & meta commentary in posts. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Debug questions require a [mre]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Comment: "The where clause is a number" `'16721216370'` is a string. Is `NUMINAMI`?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, yes `WHERE` works just fine when used with `JOIN`.

Long answer is that you've got some bad data in your file(s).  Likely a numeric field with character data.

Your job log should have a `CPD4019` with more information including the relative record number with the bad data.

Assuming you're using a supported version of the OS and are up-to-date on fixes, you could use the [VALIDATE_DATA stored proc](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=us-validate-data-validate-data-file-validate-data-library-table-functions) to check for invalid data.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(SYSTOOLS.VALIDATE_DATA_FILE('MEDLIB', 'OVLETTRES'));

SELECT * FROM TABLE(SYSTOOLS.VALIDATE_DATA_FILE('MEDCPOF', 'SPTML0'));
```